# Deploy Shield encryption & run tests in same deployment - fails

Tags: platform-encryption, ci

### Given

- You have a CI org with a class that does
  `[Select Id From SomeObject WHERE Field__c IN :vals]`
- Tests run fine in the CI org

### When

- You decide to `deterministically, case-insensitive` encrypt `Field__c`
- You make the change in your sandbox org; manually starting apex tests runs just fine
- You commit the `CustomField` metadata change to source control
- Your branch has a webhook that triggers a CI deployment to the CI org - thus deploying the encryption metadata and then running all tests

### Result

- The tests in the CI org (*remember, you didn't deploy any code changes*) now fail for the class that does the SOQL. Rows aren't returned.

> Now, why does this happen?

### Hypothesis

Encrypting a custom field via a metadata change is asynchronous as SFDC has to run some background process to make sure you don't violate any restriction. You can even see this in the UI.  Typically, this takes about 1 minute.

But for some reason this messes up the metadata deploy/run tests process because even tests that run 20+ minutes later as part of "run all" tests fail.

If you deploy without running any tests and then run tests later, the tests all pass.

> What I don't understand is given the rather short (~1 min) time period to verify that the encryption-enablement can proceed that tests in the CI org fail, even if they are started many, many minutes later in the deployment "event".