# Order of deployment of a new Custom Object from UAT to PROD

Tags: change-set

i'm new to deploying new object to PROD. I would like to know the order of adding components to outbound changeset in UAT. currently i have below around new custom object.

1. Process Builder
2. workflow rule
3. A trigger
4. A schedule batch class.
5. report types and Reports.
6. App and Tab?

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to move custom object by the change set or wants to move these components by change set. These components does not look anyhow dependent on each other so you can move them in any order. Also if you move everything together in one change set then you don't need to worry about the order.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter in which order you add the components to your Change Set. The platform tracks dependencies between components and will assist you in constructing your Change Set by "spidering" dependencies and adding them to the Change Set for you.

When you upload and deploy the Change Set, all of the included components will be deployed in a single operation.

You need to be concerned about order of deployment only if you are migrating multiple Change Sets, in which case you need to be aware of the dependencies between components in the different Change Sets and deploy those Change Sets with required dependency components first.

Comment: N.B. There's an [edge case on deployment order dependency involving encryption](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281154/deploy-shield-encryption-run-tests-in-same-deployment-fails).  Doesn't apply to OP